# JavaFX: Rotation based slider/selector (Radio-Knob)

Tags: javafx, rotation, slider, rounding

I was playing around on the JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 today, and noticed that the rotation options for various controls have a circular 'slider'.

**Image**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e29Ku.gif

I really like this, and I want to use it in a small project I'm working on, but I don't think it's a standard javafx control. It looks as though it's been designed to fit the look and feel of JavaFX, and being that it's part of a piece of software developed by the guys behind Java, I would assume it's got to be somewhere!

Do you know whether this is included in the standard javafx libraries? I'd rather not have to make it myself if I can help it!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SceneBuilder 2.0 is open source](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/tip/apps/scenebuilder/?at=default) with a 3 clause BSD license (which is liberal as far as the licensing spectrum goes).

You can find source for the "RotateEditor" control in this bitbucket mirror:

- [RotateEditor.java](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/tip/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderKit/src/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/inspector/editors/RotateEditor.java?at=default)
- [RotateEditor.fxml](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/tip/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderKit/src/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/panel/inspector/editors/RotateEditor.fxml?at=default)

The SceneBuilder source is split into two parts - the SceneBuilder application and a separate support library called SceneBuilderKit.  If you download the source from bitbucket and compile the SceneBuilderKit, you should be able to use the RotateEditor (and a bunch of other features that SceneBuilder provides).  I'm not sure if you will be able to use it directly in your application without modification or if you will need to make some small changes to successfully integrate it.

Build instructions for SceneBuilder are on the [open-jfx wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX), but you probably not need to build the whole of JavaFX to get what you need.

If the RotateEditor is not in the [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) project, you could consider re-packaging it and donating it to ControlsFX as it would be nice to have such a control in a dedicated controls library.

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea for your answer - this is very helpful! Something like this really **should** be part of a more widely used library - it seems too useful to omit!